# Same question reopened twice in 24 hrs

Tags: discussion

I have seen several questions reopened within 24hrs that had absolutely no changes. I get the impression that there is a single person reopening some items
without much thought.

I am not sure what the minimum requirement is for a user to be able to reopen questions and/or if there is a limit to the number of questions a single user can reopen? It would be good if there is a maximum that one can reopen per day and that possible is related to

- ones reputation
- the number of actually reopened questions that the user has triggered for reopening in the last X days.

Is there something like that in place? (and if it is shouldn't the rules be tightened?).

Answer (score 5):

Questions need a number of reopen votes to be reopened -- only a moderator can do it with one vote. I think what you're seeing is [this network wide change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/154627), which caused many more questions to be added to the reopen queue. Apparently enough reviewers thought those deserved to be reopened. You can vote to close them again (I'm pretty sure), or if there is an egregious mistake in reopening, you can flag the question for a moderator to review.

Comment: Thanks I missed that change announcement. I still got the impression that the same things came up yesterday and today, I will keep an eye on that and report/complain when its seems inappropriate.